# How do I remove clogged filament around a nozzle

Tags: troubleshooting, pla, nozzle

**Problem:** The first layer on the bed was printed fine, but it seems the filament got stuck or something and wouldn't stick to the bed, but instead to the nozzle. Note, it also got behind the blue rubber part. This is the work of about half an hour of printing.

**Info:**

- Anycubic Kobra
- stock nozzle
- stock bed
- [PLA filament](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0834W5L3L)
- nozzle temp: 200 °C
- bed temp: 60 °C

**Question:** How would I go on about removing the filament around the nozzle?

**Attempt:** I tried to cut it away, but it has already dried out, making it quite hard. I did some research, but I could only find ways to unclog the nozzle itself (given that the nozzle can be reached, which is not the case). My fear is, if I continue to try to break it off, I'll break the whole part. I could heat up the nozzle hoping for the filament to melt again, but that'll probably make it worse.

[image: Photo of a blob of filament stuck around the nozzle]

Comment: Note that following the selected answer is likely to remove the material as desired. It is not a certainty that your blob is caused by collecting filament from the bed. Ensure that you have a properly seated nozzle. Have you recently changed the nozzle? If so, it's important that the nozzle seats against the heat break and not against the heat block.

Comment: Yes, I'll look into what caused the problem. I also think that it has to do with the nozzle itself and that the whole thing didn't come from it collecting filament off the bed, rather it clogged up because some collected at the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need heat to remove that. If you're hesitant to heat up the hotend, you can use a soldering iron or a butter knife heated over a lighter to start attacking the blob from the outside to get it down to a more managable size. A heat gun or even a hair dryer is also an option; the latter won't melt it, but may soften it enough to be pliable.

Once you get the bulk of the blob off and are able to remove the silicone sock, a brass wire brush is the tool to use to clean off the remainder. To do this, the hotend needs to be hot, and you need to avoid brushing around where the wires go in so you don't accidentally break the wire insulation and cause a short. If there's plastic stuck there at the base of the wires, a toothpick can be used to remove it while the hotend is hot.